# Why am I getting a syntax error in my PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I apologize I'm very new to PostgreSQL. When I try and run a migration that works for everyone else, I get errors on my computer. I took the script that's failing from the migration and ran it in pgAdmin3 to see what was going on.

Here is my query:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_admin_question_export_text;

CREATE VIEW vw_admin_question_export_text AS
select name || '|' || q.question_key || '|' || qt.type_name || '|' || qo.options import from question q 
full JOIN (SELECT question_id, COALESCE(string_agg(option_text || '|' || option_value, '|'),'') as options
FROM question_option
GROUP BY question_id) qo
on (q.question_id = qo.question_id)
JOIN question_type qt
on (q.questiontype_id = qt.questiontype_id);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "import"
LINE 4: ...n_key || '|' || qt.type_name || '|' || qo.options import fro...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "import"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 179
```

My coworker thinks it may be an issue with my PostgreSQL version which is 9.5.2

Comment: What is `import` doing there?  Did this query ever really run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that [`import` is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html#KEYWORDS-TABLE), so you can't use it as an alias without double-quoting it or using `AS` keyword.

Simpler test:

```
postgres=# SELECT 'foo' import;
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at or near "import"
LINE 1: SELECT 'foo' import;
                     ^
LOCATION:  scanner_yyerror, scan.l:1082

postgres=# SELECT 'foo' AS import;
 import 
--------
 foo
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT 'foo' "import";
 import 
--------
 foo
(1 row)
```

To solve your issue, you can simple add `AS` keyword to define the alias:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_admin_question_export_text AS
select
    name || '|' || q.question_key || '|' || qt.type_name || '|' || qo.options AS import
from question q 
full JOIN (
    SELECT
        question_id,
        COALESCE(string_agg(option_text || '|' || option_value, '|'),'') as options
    FROM question_option
    GROUP BY question_id
) qo
    on (q.question_id = qo.question_id)
JOIN question_type qt
    on (q.questiontype_id = qt.questiontype_id);
```

Another option is to simple chose another name, that does not collide with one in reserved keyword list (I recommend that option). In any case, always use `AS` is a good idea to make things more explicit and avoid problems like this one.